# How do I expose embedded webkit/webview app on OSX for Selenium test automation?

Tags: selenium, testing, webview, automation, embedded-browser

I'm looking for a way to expose embedded view browser for selenium automation on Mac OSX. On Windows we have exposed CEF using `settings.remote_debugging_port = 2012`. Is there any similar way to do the same on Webview/Mac OSX?